# Proving that an infinite sum equals a Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, summation, lebesgue-integral

The problem is from Bass. I have to prove

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(p+k)^2} = - \int_0^1 \frac{x^p}{1-x}\log x \ \mathrm{d}x$$

I am lost on this. I am trying to find some sequence I can use to use one of the convergence theorems, but I can't come up with one. Is that even an approach that would work?

Answer (score 0):

$HINT$ $$\frac{x}{1-x}=\sum_{k \in \Bbb{N}} x^k ,\forall x \in [0,1)$$

Then apply Beppo-Levy Theorem to the non-negative functions on $[0,1)$ $$f_k(x)=x^{p+k-1}(-\log{x})$$

To tackle the integrals of $f_k$ make the change of variable $x=e^t$

Comment: Would it be better to write:$\frac{x}{1-x}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^k, \forall x\in[0,1[$.

Comment: @Quantic_Solver yes  you are right..thank you for the correction..!

Comment: But we need $f_k(x) \leq f_{k+1} (x)$, which is not the case here.

Comment: Not excactly..in Beppo Levi you need just the functions to be non-negative

Comment: I thought Beppo-Levi was the Monotone Convergence Theorem, but I assume it can also be done with the MCT right?

Comment: Yes because of the non negativity of the functions,the partial sums are increasing and non-negative